# Any way to call odi package or interface through the oracle database

Tags: plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I need to execute the odi package/mapping through database parametric procedure along with that i need to capture the package/Mapping status(Failed/Passed) in procedure .

ODI Version : 12c

i have tried the mentioned code and it's showing the attached error message:[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Create a plsql procedure that will run a shell script/line command
2. The line command will call an ODI scenario of a map.

You can achieve the first point by [reading this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533837800346646784).

PL/SQL procedure that executes a command line:

```sql
create or replace procedure host( cmd in varchar2 )
as
status number;
begin
dbms_pipe.pack_message( cmd );
status := dbms_pipe.send_message( 'HOST_PIPE' );
if ( status <> 0 ) then raise_application_error( -20001, 'Pipe error' );
end if;
end;
/
```

Second point it's written in the ODI documentation, at chapter [7.3.2 Executing Scenario from command line](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/administer-develop/running_executions.htm#ODIAD620).

Comment: Yes, the way is in my answer.. read it or tell me what you don't like .. make a procedure that will execute the below statement: (extract from [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/administer-develop/running_executions.htm#ODIAD620))
**On UNIX systems**:

./startscen.sh -INSTANCE=<ODIInstanceName> <scenario_name> <scenario_version> <context_code> [<log_level>] [-AGENT_URL=<remote_agent_url>] [-ASYNC=yes|no] [-NAME=<local_agent_name>] [-SESSION_NAME=<session_name>] [-KEYWORDS=<keywords>] [<variable>=<value>]*

Comment: @RajeshKumar, the example is already in the post. There you can see the code to create a procedure. After you create it, you can launch commands like this: `exec host('./abc.sh');`

Comment: Why i am getting the error message when i am try to create the the mentioned procedure ?

Comment: So the error is when you save the procedure? Not when you run it?

Comment: Any help on calling odi package/os command through Pl/sql procedure ?

Comment: I have already tried this one on oracle database, error message is attached above.

Comment: DECLARE
cmd VARCHAR2(2000) :='MKDIR TEMP4624D36';
status number;
begin
dbms_pipe.pack_message( cmd );
status := dbms_pipe.send_message( 'HOST_PIPE' );
if ( status <> 0 ) then raise_application_error( -20001, 'Pipe error' );
end if;
end;      this block is running fine but directory is not getting created.

Comment: @RajeshKumar ah .. I just made a confusion .. sorry that I said that this is not a plsql procedure and is a ODI procedure .. I confused with another question.

Comment: @RajeshKumar , are your sure that the folder isn’t created? Maybe the user that creates the folder is different than the user with whom you are checking the creation of the folder!