# Call odi Mappig through PL/SQl Procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle-data-integrator

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnbAl.png)I have an anonymous block mentione below , i want to replace the execute immediate statement with the odi scenarion .

Any way of doing it with odi procedure. If i can use any odi api or odi utilities command to replace it.

i.e:

> OdiStartScen "-SCEN_NAME=LD_T_RD_ACCOUNT_POC" "-SCEN_VERSION=001"
>   "-CONTEXT=GLOBAL" "-LOG_LEVEL=6" "-AGENT_CODE=OracleDIAgent1"
>   "-SYNC_MODE=1";

```
DECLARE

   VAR            VARCHAR2(2000);
   VAR2           DATE;

BEGIN
   BEGIN
         Select XYZ INTO VAR
         From DUMMY
         Where ID= 2; end;

       BEGIN

          l_exec_sql:= 'INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES('1')';

      IF VAR LIKE 'XY%' THEN
       execute immediate(l_exec_sql); --Replace it with odi scenario
      ELSE
       IF FUNCTION_F(VAR) THEN
          execute immediate(l_exec_sql); --Replace it with odi scenario
       END IF;
      END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to call odi package or interface through the oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144399/any-way-to-call-odi-package-or-interface-through-the-oracle-database)

Comment: Any other way of calling odi scenario from odi procedure. This database stuff is not working

Comment: Let's consider this, i have a PL/SQl block and i have placed that anonymous block in odi procedure , there are few  if conditions based upon that i want to execute the odi scenario , Solution i  am thinking as of now is use anonymous block in command on source and odi tools technology on command on target , but the problem is how i can combine these two.

Comment: @RAJESHKUMAR, I don't understand your second comment (suppose that you are both RAJESH KUMAR and Rajesh Kumar - 2 accounts). Regarding your first comment, please post errors or tell us why the database stuff is not working, in order to help you

Comment: @F.Lazarescu i have posted the query as answer please check the scenario and help me.

Comment: @RAJESHKUMAR, you should delete the "answer" and edit your first question and write there. Anyway, you can achieve what you need, by writing a ODI Package. Edit your question, delete the answer and I will write you an answer trying to guide you to create an ODI Package.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your anonymous block, you should rewrite it like this:

- Create a new ODI package;
- Create new variable named VAR (or how you like it), inside the var, put what you need, pairing with the proper logical schema;
- open the newly create ODI Package, drag-and-drop the variable and choose the Refresh Variable Type (see below picture);
- after drag-and-drop variable, choose it again and drag-and-drop, this time choosing the type Evaluate variable, and the write your first condition (see picture below);
- then drag and drop what ODI scenario do you need;

You can "play" in many more ways with the odi package variables. For example, you can create a variable that will return YES if the first condition is meet and NO if second one is meet. Your variable will execute an sql statement and will return a value (only one row, one column) and then you will evaluate it and choose what scenario to execute.

Hope that it was useful

[image: EVALUATE VARIABLE]
[image: refresh variable]

EDIT 1:

You can call an ODI Scenario from ODI Procedure, but the techonology should be ODI Tools, for the task that will call the scenario.

For your example you can do like this:
* inside your plsql block, where you have "--Replace it with odi scenario", place this substitution variables : **""**; on the second variable evaluate, place **""** etc;
* in the same procedure, make another task and write something like this:

```
<$
if (var.equals("call secenario 1") {
$>
OdiStartScen "-SCEN_NAME=NAMEOFSCENARIO" "-SCEN_VERSION=001"
<$
}
$>
```

This new task should have Techonology: ODI Tools.

**You can't call the scenario in the same task that will run the plsql procedure, because the PLSQL procedure will need Technology Oracle and the calling of scenario will need ODI Tools.**

**EDIT 2:**

To see the value in operator, go to your ODI Procedure, and please check the next option for each of your task. Save an regenerate the scenario (if you have a scenario):

[image: CHECK LOG FINAL COMMAND]

EDIT 3:

Where to see the code in Operator:
Double click the session > choose the task you want to see> expand it> double click > Code

[image]

Comment: technology: oracle

DECLARE 
 TRIG_MAP              VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
IF(TRUE) THEN

<$ TRIG_MAP="CASE_1"; $> NULL;
ELSE

<$ TRIG_MAP="CASE_2"; $> NULL;

END IF;
END;
-----------------------------------------
technology: GROOVY

<$=TRIG_MAP$> 

if i click on the execute option then it's getting failed and printed the code in operator , second case when execute option is unchecked then it execute successfuly and code is not shown.
in first case where there is a code failure i can see the value of TRIG_MAP which comes as case 2 i don't know why.

Comment: In order to don’t fail, you need to comment the code like this: /* code *\.  So it’s ok to be case 2? It should be CASE_2, correct?

Comment: it should be CASE_1 , as IF statement  will always be true it should return CASE_1.

Comment: So the task 1 and 2 are ok? Check task 3: is the call of the scenario correctly written?

Comment: can you share the working code at your end so i can develop the code by copying the already running code.

Comment: the code it's exactly like yours. I don't understand .. you said last week that it's running without errors but it doens't call the scenario. In his case you need to check the conditions .. or the last task, because you saw that in task 2, variable TRIG_MAP it's returning a valid value ..

Comment: Variable TRIG_MAP  is returning CASE_2 as value so i put case_2 in If statement but the odi tool technology is returning error,  i am using odi 12c do you think this might causing the error due to odi version as i can see you are using odi 11g.

Comment: No, i’m having also 12c. Copy paste the error please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197812/discussion-between-f-lazarescu-and-rajesh-kumar).

Comment: Value it's printing it CASE_2 along with error message /*ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed. 
Caused By: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CASE_2 for class: Task2
 at org.codehaus.groovy.bsf.GroovyEngine.exec(GroovyEngine.java:114)
 at com.sunopsis.dwg.codeinterpretor.SnpScriptingInterpretor.execInBSFEngine(SnpScriptingInterpretor.java:396)*/

Comment: Did you found any solution @F.Lazarescu ?

Comment: Give me the code for task 3, please. Edit your question an post it there. You can put it also in chat.

Comment: This is code for task 3: I am trying to edit  the question it showing formatting error:<$
if (TRIG_MAP.equals("CASE_2") {
$>
OdiStartScen "-SCEN_NAME=SCEN1" "-SCEN_VERSION=001"
<$
}
$>

Comment: @RajeshKumar , the technology is odi tools, yes?